# More than just repositories with VisualSVN Server?

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server

I recently installed  VisualSVN Server and have several repositories migrated to the server. It works charmingly.

However, I was wondering, is it possible to host files that are not in a repository within the local network using VisualSVN Server in addition to the hosted repositories?

Specifically, All of my repositories are stored in the local directory F:Repositories they are accessible in a browser via "https://MyServer.com/svn/". What I want to do is leave the repositories mapped to that location so they are accessible as usual, but I also want to host files in C:\Data and/or F:\Data somewhere using the same instance of Apache. I would like to host it in either "https://MyServer.com/Data/" or something similar even as a subdirectory of /svn/. Can I do this and if so how?

I couldn't find any documentation on doing this. So I have tried editing the *.conf files that are used to configure Apache server in the VisualSVN Server in a number of ways, but have been entirely unable to make any headway.

Comment: Editing the conf files is the way to go. It's been a while but, when I dealt with it, it was just a standard Apache web server. Just look around for "directory alias apache", and you should find some answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache HTTP Server instance of VisualSVN Server is isolated and is not intended to be used as general-purpose web server.

Check the disclaimer in `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\httpd.conf`:

```
# This is configuration file for Apache HTTP server which is
# part of VisualSVN Server.
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE IT WILL BE REGENERATED AUTOMATICALLY BY VISUALSVN SERVER
#
# Contact with VisualSVN Ltd. (support@visualsvn.com) if you have suggestions and
# improvements.
```

I suppose that you can complete the task that you describe by manually modifying `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\httpd-custom.conf`. However I strongly advise you to consider using separate web server for serving regular files, web pages, whatever.

Comment: Using `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\httpd-custom.conf` should be a save way to go, as also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/638698/694576